# FOSUser Bundle, Symfony Landing Page

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using the FOSUser Bundle for Symfony... My question is;
I have two different group of users.... For example; Teachers and Students, which it is set when they register to the system. (using the user table of FOSUser Bundle)

After a successful login, I want to user to go to  the correct landing page.. So 
If the user is a teacher, I want the user to go to /teacher and for student to /student.

What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an event listener to listen for an login event. Then you can route the client to different pages based on their roles.

**services.yml:**

```
services:
    login_listener:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\Listener\LoginListener
        arguments: [@security.context, @doctrine]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login }
```

**LoginListener:**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine; // for Symfony 2.1.x
// use Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine; // for Symfony 2.0.x

/**
 * Custom login listener.
 */
class LoginListener
{
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext */
    private $securityContext;

    /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
    private $em;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param SecurityContext $securityContext
     * @param Doctrine        $doctrine
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, Doctrine $doctrine)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->em              = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * Do the magic.
     * 
     * @param  Event $event
     */
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(Event $event)
    {
        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_1')) {
            // redirect 1
        }

        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_2')) {
            // redirect 2
        }

        // do some other magic here
        $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

        // ...
    }
}
```

From: http://www.metod.si/login-event-listener-in-symfony2/